# How to preempt a ProgressDialog?

Tags: android

App I'm building is carrying out a task, ProgressDialog is on the screen circling 'round and 'round.

How can I provide the user the ability to break out of that Dialog at any given time, immediately disappear the Dialog and stop the task from being carried out mid run?

Comment: stop the task means which task, is it AsyncTask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ,if it is an AsynkTask:

```
dialog = ProgressDialog.show(
                        Activity.this,
                        "",
                        "Loading the results...Please wait.",
                        true,
                        true,
                        new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener(){
                            @Override
                            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                                *YourTask*.this.cancel(true); 
                            }
                        }
                );
```

Comment: I tried this but the *YourTask*.this.cancel(true); statement was throwing a red circled 'X' in the left margin.  Nothing I try gets around that.  However if I omit keyword ".this" it will compile and run the same as Lalit's.  Don't know what I'm doing wrong.  Thank you for the suggestion though.

Comment: Okay, thanks to all who have responded.  What I've done is replace the *YourTask*.this.cancel(true); statement line with these two lines:                      whatever.cancel(true);
                  finish();
This both disappears the message dialog as well as returns user from the Asynced task back to the main navigation page in the prog.  Works perfectly.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure out what to put into the *YourTask* placeholder that nibha has posted.  (I've tried nibha's snip in the same spot in the class where Lalit Poptani's shorter snip succesfully just disappears the dialog message only.)  Anyway, the following is the class (with declarations and other stuff removed for simplicity in conveying the question).  It paints something onto the screen.  I just want the routine to immediately stop at the same time the message dialog disappears.  (Thanks again for any help):

```
public class WhateverActivity extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mWhatView = new WhateverView(this);
        setContentView(mWhatView);
        whatever = new Whatever();
        whatever.addListener(mWhatView);
        whatever.execute(this);
        mDialog = ProgressDialog.show( 
                WhateverActivity.this, 
                "", 
                "Loading the results...Please wait.", 
                true, 
                true, 
                new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener(){ 
                    @Override 
                    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) { 
                        *YourTask*.this.cancel(true);  
                    } 
                } 
        );
    }

    private class WhateverView extends View implements WhateverListener {
        @Override
        public void whateverDone() {
        }

        @Override
        public void whateverPart(ArrayList<Float> list) {
            synchronized (this) {
                Iterator<Float> iter = list.iterator(); 
                    ...
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
            ...
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            synchronized (this) {
                if (mBitmap != null) {                  
                    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, null);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```